# Servlet <url-pattern>: Trouble Mapping to a Directory that's Below My Application Directory

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

I want to have a dedicated directory for jsp and servlet development, but I can't map my app's logical name resource correctly. I tested the app without the extra directory as follow:

`C:\tomcat1\webapps\beer-v1`

The app ran successfully. But if I map the application to(my desired location):

`C:\tomcat1\webapps\dev\beer-v1`

The application does not run. I get a 404 error, resource not found. The following is my web.xml file.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.web.BeerSelect</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: That is not possible - http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming . But you should be able to name the folder `dev#beer-v1`. Or alternatively you can use different host for your development (which means a different `webapps` folder).